# Program for detecting and installing drivers

Tags: windows-xp, drivers

I bought [Asus 5250](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B007NHP3O6/ref=noref?ie=UTF8&psc=1&s=computers) (just with better processor). And problem is, the notebook wasn't ship with operating system, so I installed Windows XP SP2 which I've bought for my previous desktop computer. Installation went fine but it seems that drivers are supported only for Windows Vista and above (I was able to install only LAN drivers from the installation CD, all other installation fails). I've also tried to download and install drivers from Asus homepage and it didn't work too (I ran their hardware vendor detection tool but it told me only manufacturer of the hardware).

So is there some free program which can detect what kind of hardware I exactly have and possible download me the drivers?(I tried Everest but it didn't find my WLAN adapter which seems really strange).

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: I don't believe that anyone except the manufacturer can create a programm fitting all your requirements

Comment: Well, I am getting kind of desperate here because I've spent few hours fixing it yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

If the manufacturer doesn't supply drivers you can try to see what hardware your computer has with SIW or a similar tool. A good source for drivers is [driverpacks.net](http://driverpacks.net/). These are compressed archives full of drivers.